# Remove powered by oneall in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

hi all i have developed website using opencart 2.0 and i used one all plugin for Facebook connect ..
now i need to remove tat Powered by one all is there any option to remove??

And i have used only facebook login..if there is any other option to login with facebook please let me know tat 
[image: image1]

```
// Display widget in this container
$oasl_container = 'oneall_social_login_'.mt_rand(99999, 9999999); 
$title = "";
// Do not display for guests
if ( ! $oasl_user_is_logged  && ! empty ($oasl_subdomain)) 
{
 if (! empty ($oasl_heading_title))
    {
  //echo '<h3>'.$oasl_heading_title.'</h3>';
  echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
 }                    

 if ($oasl_display_modal) 
 { 
  echo '<a id="'.$oasl_container.'" class="button">'.$oasl_login_button.'</a>';
 }
 else

 {
  echo '<div id="'.$oasl_container.'"></div>';
 }

 // Plugin
 $oasl_widget = array();
 $oasl_widget[] = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
 $oasl_widget[] = "/ OneAll Social Login - http://www.oneall.com/ /";
 $oasl_widget[] = "var oneall = oneall || [];";
 $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'set_providers', ['" . $oasl_providers. "']]);";
 $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'set_callback_uri', '" . $oasl_callback_uri . "']);";

 // Modal Popup 
 if ($oasl_display_modal)
 {
  $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'attach_onclick_popup_ui', '" . $oasl_container . "']);";
 }
 // Inline Display
 else
 {
  $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'set_grid_size', 'x', " . $oasl_grid_size_x . "]);";
  $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'set_grid_size', 'y', " . $oasl_grid_size_y . "]);";
     $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'set_custom_css_uri', '" .  $oasl_custom_css_uri . "']);";
     $oasl_widget[] = "_oneall.push(['social_login', 'do_render_ui', '" . $oasl_container . "']);";
 }
  $oasl_widget[] = "</script>";

 // Display Widget     
  echo "\n\t" . implode ("\n\t", $oasl_widget)."\n"; 

}
```

Comment: Yes selva, You con do it with import **facebook.php** and **fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt** . [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) provide such kind of ready made code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by `css`.
Put a div and  class `hide-pby`(example) outside `iframe`.

```
.hide-pby{
     position:relative;
}
aside.hide-pby::before{
     position:absolute; 
     width:200px; 
     height:15px;content:"";
     left:0;
     bottom:0; 
     background-color:#fff;
}
```